# API url printing one specific item with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I have made some code were you can `console.log()` one item from a fetch.

If I want to `console.log()` the `lat` property from `data` it works. Now, I want to `console.log()` the `pop` property element from the API. The `pop` property is inside the `hourly` array. I think (see url in the code).

But there is a problem, I cant get this to print in either the console or HTML. Can anyone help me `console.log()` the `pop` property from the API fetch?

```
<body>
<p>De regen percentage is: <br><span id="pop"></span></p>
<script>
  const api_url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=52.1092717&lon=5.1809676&&exclude=current,minutely,timezone,alerts&appid=add524720c6b11d0649d761f76e953c8';
  async function getRain(){
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const  data = await response.json();
    const {lat} = data;
    console.log(lat);
    document.getElementById('pop').textContent = lat;
  }
  getRain();
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to access the pop property. The hourly property is an array so you need to loop through the array to access each pop value. If you want to access a specific value, you can filter the hourly property for elements in the array that meet your condition.

```
<body>
<p>De regen percentage is: <br><span id="pop"></span></p>
<script>
  const api_url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=52.1092717&lon=5.1809676&&exclude=current,minutely,timezone,alerts&appid=add524720c6b11d0649d761f76e953c8';
  async function getRain(){
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const  data = await response.json();
    const {lat, hourly} = data;
    console.log(lat);
    hourly.forEach(element => {
       console.log(element.pop);
    });
    document.getElementById('pop').textContent = lat;
  }
  getRain();
</script>
</body>
```

Filtered example:
Here I am looping through (filtering) the hourly array for elements where the temp is greater than 283.

```
console.log(hourly.filter(a => a.temp > 283))
```

If you want to print all the pop data from the api in the HTML element like your comment suggests, you can do it in the following way:
I am using the map function to loop through the array and return each pop value.

```
const popArr = hourly.map(ele => ele.pop);

document.getElementById('pop').textContent = popArr;
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. Personal preference I wouldn't use `e` to describe an element or item, because `e` is tipically used for `event`. If you could add an explenation to how `filter()` works it would be a better answer.

Comment: Yes, correct I have made the edit.

Comment: Nice thanks! In the console the pop data in printed, but now i only want to print the pop data in the   'document.getElementById('pop').textContent = lat;'.  Lat isnt needed anymore. I am new to javascript so idk how everything works. If i put pop instead of lat, i will get the message [object HTMLSpanElement] on my screen

Comment: Check my updated edit for an example of how to show pop on the page

Comment: Thanks it printed! but i threw it. how to print it only 1 time?

Comment: Well the hourly property has many elements in the array and each element has a pop property, so you will need to filter the hourly array for whichever pop you want to display on the page. They are all 0, but that may not be true in the future. Some may have different values which is why you have to filter.

Comment: Just the first pop is alright. each day the pop value will change based on the api data. If it only prints the first pop so in this case 0 it is good and then i can publish my first site.